# display edge attribute values in networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Expanding on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381460/networkx-how-to-show-node-and-edge-attributes-in-a-graph-drawing), Is it possible to only display values of edge attributes?

For instance, currently using

```
paragraph = """
John is a computer scientist. John eats mango. John has an elder sister named Mary.
"""

mg.make_graph(paragraph) #This is my custom method, which creates the following graph

nx.draw(mg,pos=graphviz_layout(mg,prog='neato'),arrows=True,with_labels=True,alpha=0.5,linewidths=0.5,scale=2)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(mg, pos = graphviz_layout(mg, prog='neato'),labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(mg,'label'))
plt.show()
```

I am getting this [image: Output]

However I only want the value of the attribute and not the key itself. (The word 'label' must not be printed.

I understand this is because `nx.get_edge_attributes(mg,'label')` returns a dictionary, but using `nx.get_edge_attributes(mg,'label').values()` in the `labels` parameter, also does not result in the graph being displayed with only values.

How can I achieve this? (i.e, only the value must be printed in edge and not the key *label*).

Answer (score -1):

How about something along the lines of:

```
labels = {e: mg.get_edge_data(e[0], e[1])["label"] for e in mg.edges()}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(mg, pos=graphviz_layout(mg, prog='neato'), edge_labels=labels)
```

`labels` needs to be a dictionary with edges as keys and labels you want to be drawn as values.
Note that I put the argument containing `labels` as `edge_labels` since it is the name in version 1.10 and 2. But I think you can adapt if you have an older version.

Comment: Error in     labels = {e: e["label"] for e in mg.edges()}
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: yes, it was not an exact answer. But try this: `mg.get_edge_data(e)["label"]` or `mg[e[0]][e[1]]["label"]` instead of `e["label"]`.

Comment: none working, i think, the function itself takes a dictionary as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, I finally tried it myself and I edited the answer.

Comment: File "inference.py", line 44, in <dictcomp>
    labels = {e: mg.get_edge_data(e[0], e[1])["label"] for e in mg.edges()}
KeyError: 'label'

Comment: This means that maybe one of your edges doesn't have the `"label"` attribute.
I can't help any further if you don't give the `make_graph` function because I can't test it on my own.